# Windows Azure hanging on when starting without debugging

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm currently running Azure SDK 1.6 and am having troubles starting the Azure instance locally without debugging.

It's hanging on "Starting the roles for the application in the Windows Azure compute emulator ..." step.

Strangely enough when I hit Debug, the project starts.

Additionally the project does not pick up any HTML/CSS/Code changes when I run in debug mode.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and/or have a solution?

I've seen this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/ad362016-16f6-459a-8022-9307aa5f910e

and this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/05dbf84c-4929-40b4-82b2-f7747227d541

But both do not seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have any startup tasks?  I have been using Azure since the 1.0 SDK and had numerous weird issues like this over time.  The last couple SDKs have been really stable especially the 1.8...I know this is not your question, but figured if u can update to 1.8.

Comment: Are your `Windows Azure compute emulator` same version as SDK?

Comment: We're currently running 1.6 here. We don't have any startup tasks defined. I've done some more digging since then and realized we've been running in "Hosted Web Core" mode. I've tried to since swap it over to Full IIS mode by adding the <sites> definition. I'm now getting Object not found errors when I start and try to access the site in my web.config on this line:         <add name="TableStorageRoleProvider" type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageRoleProvider" description="Role provider using table storage" applicationName="NameAnalyzer" />

Comment: Note that we've had no problems running locally in Hosted Web Core mode, except we can only run in debug mode (f5) and we can't modify files and have them reflected right away (a big headache).

Comment: @VMAtm - My compute emulator and SDK are the same version.